# Using search to display entries based on a value in a number field

Tags: search, elementcriteriamodel

I'm trying to return results based on a year stored in a custom field. For example, returning entries with a model year greater than 2006 and less than 2009. Is there a search syntax to support this?

For example: `for entry in craft.entries.section('equipment').search(modelYear: > 2006 && < 2009) …`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a certain amount of logic in the [ElementCriteriaModel syntax](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel#parameter-value-syntax). I think this will work:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('equipment').modelYear('and, > 2006, < 2009') %}
{% for entry in entries %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```